# How to properly check if a prefix of a word exists in a trie?

Tags: java, trie

Currently I have the "searchPrefix" function of my Trie class defined as such:

```
public Boolean searchPrefix(String word) {
    TrieNode temp = this.root;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        if(temp.children.get(word.charAt(i)) == null) return false;
        else temp = temp.children.get(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return (temp.children.isEmpty()) ? false : true;
}
```

This function is supposed to return "true" when the input string is a prefix of a word that exists inside of the trie object. Here is the TrieNode class for reference:

```
class TrieNode {
   Character c;
   Boolean isWord = false;
   HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();

   public TrieNode() {}
   public TrieNode(Character c) {
    this.c = c;
   }
}
```

According to this online judge, I am incorrectly determining whether a given input string is a prefix.  Can anyone shed some light as to why this is an incorrect method?  My thinking is that when we get to the node that is the end of the input string, if the node has children it is a prefix of some other word so we return true.  However this is apparently incorrect.

Comment: what about empty string? is it considered a valid prefix?

Comment: also the link to `this online judge` is missing

Comment: @Devstr the online judge is firecode.io.  Also, I'm unsure of whether or not an empty string is a prefix due to the ambiguity of the online judge's description, however putting a checker "if(word.length() < 1) return true/false" doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not handling the case where prefix is a terminal word in the trie.

For example, assume there's only one word `hello` in a trie.
Your implementation will return false for `searchPrefix("hello")`.

To fix it, you need to check the `isWord` flag too:

```
public Boolean searchPrefix(String word) {
    TrieNode temp = this.root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        TrieNode next = temp.children.get(word.charAt(i));
        if (next == null) {
            return false;
        }
        temp = next;
    }
    return !temp.children.isEmpty() || temp.isWord;
}
```